# How to handle failed connections with Flask-MQTT

Tags: python, flask, exception, mqtt

I have a Flask-Mqtt client running, and everything is fine if broker is accessible. The problem starts when the MQTT broker is not accessible. Usually, I would be able to handle the failed connections with exceptions on the on_connect function, however I don't quite understand how to implement it with Flask-Mqtt

I would want to handle failed broker connections while allowing the web server to run the web pages.

Documentations and example of Flask-MQTT: https://flask-mqtt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

The code for handling broker connection failure (based on Steve's Internet Guide)

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc==0:
        client.connected_flag=True #set flag
        print("connected OK")
    else:
        print("Bad connection Returned code=",rc)
        client.bad_connection_flag=True
```

The error on Flask app when broker not connected:

```
C:\Users\USER\Documents\College\FYP1\flask_testing\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/USER/Documents/College/FYP1/flask_testing/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/Documents/College/FYP1/flask_testing/main.py", line 37, in <module>
    mqtt = Mqtt(app)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\College\FYP1\flask_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_mqtt\__init__.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.init_app(app)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\College\FYP1\flask_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_mqtt\__init__.py", line 183, in init_app
    self._connect()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\College\FYP1\flask_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_mqtt\__init__.py", line 209, in _connect
    res = self.client.connect(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\College\FYP1\flask_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 941, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\College\FYP1\flask_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 1075, in reconnect
    sock = self._create_socket_connection()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\College\FYP1\flask_testing\venv\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 3546, in _create_socket_connection
    return socket.create_connection(addr, source_address=source, timeout=self._keepalive)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 807, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar error. Everything was working fine when the mqtt server was running but if I started the app with the server switched off, the app failed with the same message than yours.

I finally solved it by using connect_async parameter when creating the MQTT object instance.

mqtt_client = Mqtt(app, connect_async=True)

With that parameter, the web pages will be displayed and, when the mqtt server is available, it will automatically connect.